# How I get the tag value from the sender

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
- (IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender {
    // Make sure it's a UIButton
    if (![sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        return;

    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];
}
```

I understand how to get the title and other current values but I don't see how I can get the value of the tag property.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've got a test project here where I just used:

```
NSInteger i = [sender tag];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call:

```
NSInteger the_tag = ((UIView*)sender).tag;
```

Each UIButton is a subclass of UIView which contains the `tag` property.

Comment: There's no need to cast, since the id type will accept any method signature without complaining.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I'm aware of that, I'm doing to only for my own benefit in tracing what I assign/use. As soon I'll get better in tracking the object that I use/create I'll stop that useless practice.

Comment: If it's for visual tracing only, it's cleaner to just end the line with a comment (like ` // UIView*`) instead.